# Lifecycle method of spring bean after bean is created

Tags: spring

Is there any lifecycle method of bean which gets called after bean is created .

I dont want to use init or destroy callback method of bean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put `@PostConstruct` annotation on any public method of your bean class, Spring will call it after the bean is created and all its dependencies are injected.

Comment: And `@PreDestroy` but you need to use `<context:annotation-config />` or something that implies it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! there is

```
<bean id="personDet" class="com.beans.PersonDet" init-method="yourInitMyBean()">
```

There is an attribute for each bean definition i.e init-method

The method yourInitMyBean() in PersonDet class will load first time when bean is created and will never call again

Similarly there is destroy-method attribute for bean defination

```
<bean id="personDet" class="com.beans.PersonDet" destroy-method="destroyBean()">
```

The method destroyBean() will be called only when you trying to shutdown your application or when the time your closing your beanFactory , ApplicationContext call close() method.

You can put both the attribute in-order test..

Hope it helps.